# Blob storage, IIS smooth streaming or Adaptive streaming I m confused

Tags: iis, video, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to have smooth streaming capability on the cloud but I m a bit confused.

I have seen by searching the web that sooth streaming with azure blob will be supported by april we are in juin and I have seen no updates no where. Is it stile ongoing? should we wait? any news?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanuk/archive/2011/04/12/windows-azure-cdn-for-iis-smooth-streaming.aspx

I have seen this method for doing soomth streaming

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/smooth-streaming-with-windows-azure-blobs-and-cdn
He is parsing the files and recreating manifests it seems to have some limitations and potential issues with future releases and it's called Adaptive streaming instead of smooth. Is it the way to go?

I wonder also if we have to use a silverlight player or if it can be done also in HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native support in the Windows Azure CDN for Smooth Streaming is indeed still coming. It's not available yet.

The reason my solution is called "Adaptive Streaming" instead of "Smooth Streaming" is because "Smooth Streaming" refers specifically to using IIS to serve the content (so my solution, while compatible, isn't technically Smooth Streaming).

Smooth Streaming doesn't strictly require Silverlight, but that's the most common player. No browser I'm aware of natively supports the Smooth Streaming protocol.

Comment: Thx you smarx, I will be using your method until native suport is available.

Thank you for sharing :)

Comment: Technically there is no reason why one should need an IIS for Smooth Streaming. The IIS is only needed to get from the URL to a specific part of the ISMV on the server.
If you prepare the files in a way that all fragments per quality are stored in separate files you can even use a simple apache (or any CDN). I implemented this special preparation of the pre-encoded plain MP4 files in my mp4parser project in java: http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/source/browse/trunk/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/smoothstreaming/FragmentFileSet.java